# get parentNode STYLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When drop any component onto other then I want to interchange the CSS styles of parentNode of component.

**Example :**

**Before**

```
 <div class="parentDIV_1" Style="HOrizontal_interchange CSS">
      Component_1
    </div>

    <div class="parentDIV_2" Style="Vertical_interchange CSS">
       Component_2
    </div>
```

***Now i want to interchange the CSS of both class at run time(when drag & Drop)***

**After**

```
<div class="parentDIV_1" **Style="Vertical_interchange CSS"**>
      Component_1
    </div>

    <div class="parentDIV_2" **Style="HOrizontal_interchange CSS"**>
       Component_2
    </div>
```

Comment: I've never seen the attribute `css` before; is that a typo or are you adding custom attributes (which are ignored by the browser) to the DOM?

Comment: @Aaron hey that's Style. I mean to interchange the CSS of concern DIV.

Comment: Also how is the attribute `css` related to `innerHTML`? Please edit your question, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think you need more help than a jQuery solution here. Question makes very little sense and as far as I am aware you can't have a css attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this too :

```
$("#id").removeClass().addClass("Whatever_you_want_to_swap_ClassName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but it seems that you want to swap the CSS styles of two elements after some drag&drop event.

How about this solution:

1. Create four CSS classes:

   ```
    .parentDIV_1 { ... }
    .parentDIV_2 { ... }
    .horiz { ... }
    .vert { ... }
   ```
2. Assign two classes to the `div`s:

   ```
   <div class="parentDIV_1 horiz"> ...</div>

   <div class="parentDIV_2 vert"> ...</div>
   ```

Now you can toggle them:

```
    $('.horiz').toggleClass('vert').toggleClass('horiz');
    $('.vert').toggleClass('vert').toggleClass('horiz');
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with basic javascript. Learning javascript does not imply learning jquery.

Comment: The tags of the question clearly say "jquery", so I'm not sure why you insist on pure JavaScript.